# Ionic 3: How make ionViewWillEnter only when back button pressed?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have read [Navigating Lifecycle Events](https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/)

My use case here is. I had to refresh the content on page load as well as when back button pressed from another page.

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.getProjects();
}

ionViewWillEnter(){
   this.getProjects();
}
```

this works fine but of course `ionViewWillEnter` runs on first page load as well. so two api requests triggered **`(ionViewDidLoad + ionViewWillEnter)`**. Is there any way to restrict them like setting flag or something?

Comment: I guess the answer is within the question itself. 
ionViewWillEnter() will serve both the cases you mentioned above. So just use ionViewWillEnter() instead of using both.
Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Perfectly make sense @Lokkesh Thanks for it. How did I not think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use events for this purpose. Whenever user clicks back button, publish the event like this:

```
onBackButtonPressed(){
    this.events.publish('backPressed');
}
```

subscribe to this event from the page where you want to refresh the data:

```
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('backPressed', () => {
       this.getProjects();
  });
}
```

Refer this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/

The problem with this issue is you have to publish the event from all the pages to which the navigation is possible from the current page.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
  ionViewDidLoad()
  {
    this.navBar.backButtonClick = this.onClickBackButton.bind(this);
  }

  onClickBackButton(event)
  {

  }
```

Comment: I didn't understand this approach. Can you please ellaborate ?